# Using ngx-pagination on reusable component

Tags: javascript, angular, pagination

I am attempting to use ngx-pagination on a reusable datatable component, however the change in one table is effecting the change in other tables on the page. How can I assure pagination events are only occurring on one component at a time?

table.component.html

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th *ngFor="let col of cols">
                <label>{{col.header}}</label>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>    
        <tr *ngFor="let row of data | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 6, 
           currentPage: p }">`
            <td *ngFor="let col of cols">
                {{row[col.prop]}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<pagination-controls 
class="my-pagination" 
(pageChange)="p = $event">
</pagination-controls>
```

table.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-data-table',
  templateUrl: './data-table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./data-table.component.css']
})

export class DataTableComponent {

  @Input() data
  @Input() cols
  p: number = 1

}
```